# Proxy setup question

Tags: linux, proxy, ssh, squid, portforwarding

I want to be able to access a website that is IP restricted outside the UK from my cable  DSL in Germany.

A friend of mine set up a proxy server in the UK that whitelists my dedicated Debian server at a German hosting company. Since my cable DSL IP changes everyday this was the simplest setup for him.

Now, on my side I would like to set up a proxy frowarder on my dedicated Debian server to his UK proxy, in order to be able to whitelist my cable DSL IP when I need to access the particular website. I have no access to the proxy itself, apart from my Germand dedicated server's IP being whitelisted for it.

A graphic illustrates the setup:

DSL at home <------> German dedicated server <--[permitted to access]--> UK proxy <-----> UK restricted website

What tools would you recommend to set up a proxy forwarding of the UK proxy at my German dedicated server, so that my German dedicated server becomes a transparent proxy that forwards to the UK proxy? As said it is a full blown Debian system. I tried netcat port forwarding, but that didn't work.

Comment: Where is the connection for programmers? I think you should use the page Super Users (Click on 'stockExchange' on top left)

Comment: probably http://http://serverfault.com/ would be the better place to ask this.... :)

Comment: Yea indeed sorry for asking this here. There would be a chance though to incorporate a transparent proxy forwarder written in C ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, this should go to serverfault. But I think you can manage to do this using a simple iptables rule to redirect incoming traffic from a given port, to you friends web proxy.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -i eth0 -p TCP --dport 3128 --to-destination a.b.c.d
```

Where `a.b.c.d` is your friend's IP.

You can also use `a.b.c.d:port` syntax for a different listening port at your friend's host.

Edit: I have tested it on my own network using masquerading and ip forwarding.

Comment: I checked this, it doesn't work unfortunately. ip forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Do you have any iptables rule already set?